# Tracking Email opening in Outbound Email

Tags: outbound-email

We are trying to get "Tracking Email Opening" to work, using Compound Templating on 2013 SP1. We have followed the instructions as found here: [Tracking e-mail opening](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2D0A7D1A-555D-4D31-97FD-D82F9A576AF4#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-00841438-80F3-46DE-BB81-084C2859D715.xml&docid=GUID-00841438-80F3-46DE-BB81-084C2859D715&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-00841438-80F3-46DE-BB81-084C2859D715).

When Previewing or Publishing, we will find this output in the published HTML:

```
[*__TrackOpen__*]
```

What step(s) did we miss to get the tracking image displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct placeholder, which the Mailer service will then replace with the image URL once the e-mails are being sent.

To get a good idea of how the actual e-mails look, use the Test Mailing functionality rather than the preview within the CME. When you Send a Mailing, it will use the last tested version of the Mailing -- so you don't have to worry about whether people have changed the content in the meantime. You can be sure that what you last approved is what gets sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can add < img src="@@OutboundEmail_OpenTracking@@" alt="" /> tag or < img src="`[*__TrackOpen__*]`" alt="" /> in your html. Because @@OutboundEmail_OpenTracking@@ and `[*__TrackOpen__*]` only gives the path of image.

Comment: I hadn't even considered that they weren't putting it in an image tag. But indeed, he doesn't show any of that in his question. Good catch!